# C++ - read 1000 floats and insert them into a vector of size 10 by keeping the lowest 10 numbers only

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, vector, queue

So I am pretty new to c++ and I am not sure if there is a data structure already created to facilitate what I am trying to do (so I do not reinvent the wheel):

**What I am trying to do**

I am reading a file where I need to parse the file, do some calculations on every floating value on every row of the file, and return the top 10 results from the file in ascending order.

**What am I trying to optimize**
I am dealing with a 1k file and a 1.9 million row file so for each row, I will get a result that is of size 72 so in 1k row, I will need to allocate a vector of 72000 elements and for the 1.9 million rows ... well you get the idea.

**What I have so far**

I am currently working with a vector for the results which then I sort and resize it to 10.

```
const unsigned int vector_space = circularVector.size()*72;
//vector for the results
std::vector<ResultType> results;
results.reserve(vector_space);
```

but this is extremely inefficient.

**What I want to accomplish **
I want to only keep a vector of size 10, and whenever I perform a calculation, I will simply insert the value into the vector and remove the largest floating point that was in the vector, thus maintaining the top 10 results in ascending order.

**Is there a structure already in c++ that will have such behavior?**

Thanks!

Comment: Before worrying about something super elegant I'd just keep 10 numbers and sort every time you find one that's larger than the current lowest.  Probably not the most efficient way to do it, but sorting 10 numbers sometimes is likely a tiny part of the time you're spending with file i/o and whatever processing you're doing to them.  If you think it might be an issue then you can profile and see if other solutions are better but at least you have a baseline.

Comment: I think that maintaining array of top 10 results is better way, or you  can use max-heap.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It isn't just 'sometimes', it is O(N) times for *N* = 1.9 million-10.

Comment: @ejp The number of times the sort needs to be applied depends on how often a number larger than the current lowest is processed, so anywhere from never to always depending on the data.  Any solution is going to require some amount of sorting or placement in a heap, I prefer the simplest solution as a baseline and if it turns into a hotspot when profiling then I look for alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Changed to use the 10 lowest elements rather than the highest elements as the question now makes clear which is required

You can use a `std::vector` of 10 elements as a *max heap*, in which the elements are partially sorted such that the first element always contains the maximum value. Note that the following is all untested, but hopefully it should get you started.

```
// Create an empty vector to hold the highest values
std::vector<ResultType> results;

// Iterate over the first 10 entries in the file and put the results in the vector
for (... ; i < 10; i++) {
    // Calculate the value of this row
    ResultType r = ....
    // Add it to the vector
    results.push_back(r);
}

// Now that the vector is "full", turn it into a heap
std::make_heap(results.begin(), results.end());

// Iterate over all the remaining rows, adding values which are lower than the
// current maximum
for (i = 10; .....)  {
    // Calculate the value for this row
    ResultType r = ....

    // Compare it to the max element in the heap
    if (r < results.front()) {
         // Add the new element to the vector
         results.push_back(r);
         // Move the existing minimum to the back and "re-heapify" the rest
         std::pop_heap(results.begin(), results.end());
         // Remove the last element from the vector
         results.pop_back();
    }
}

// Finally, sort the results to put them all in order
// (using sort_heap just because we can)
std::sort_heap(results.begin(), results.end());
```

Comment: I think you have it all backwards. I think OP is trying to _keep_ the lowest values, and you are popping the lowest. Use _max_ heap to pop highest instead, and flip all the equality signs accordingly.

Comment: I had to guess -- the question title talks about *keeping* the 10 highest values, but the body says the OP wants to *remove* the highest value (i.e. keep the 10 lowest). If it is the lowest values that are needed, then removing the references to `std::greater` and switching the test condition should still work.

Comment: @TristanBrindle, I just corrected the title - sorry I forgot to change the title before you answered.

Comment: @TristanBrindle, I tried your suggestions on reversing it, but the values I get are all 0.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov Yeah, if `ResultType` is a `float` or a `double` then default construction would set it to zero. I've edited the answer now to avoid this.

Comment: yeah I tried different things and I was starting to realize that.. Thanks for the help! works like a charm!

Comment: @Georgi If you ever want to simplify your code some, I find [yinqiwen's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21979689/1072468) more straight forward and equally effective. Not that there is anything wrong with this answer, but I guess I just don't like the explicit `make_heap` calls.

Comment: @SchighSchagh I'm not keen on the `set` approach, as I've commented on that answer. If you want a nice class wrapper for a heap rather than calls to free functions, the STL provides `std::priority_queue` which provides just that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What you want is a *priority queue* or *heap,* defined so as to remove the lowest value. You just need to do such a remove if the size after the insertion is greater than 10. You should be able to do this with STL classes.

Comment: It's typically called (or "I think you mean") a priority queue, or a heap. And one can just say max-heap instead of "in inverse order". And it's preferable to give a short description of a data structure when mentioning it as an answer - [Is mentioning a well-known data structure or algorithm considered a link-only answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212919)

Comment: @Dukeling Most of that discussion is, irrelevantly, about link-only answers themselves. There isn't much there to suggest that anybody actually consider algorithm-name-only answers to be equal to link-only answers. I don't. A link-only answer is only valid for the lifetime of the link, and doesn't actually convey that the poster knows anything about the matter himself. In any case this isn't an algorithm-name-only answer. It seems to me to agree entirely with case 1 in the question in your link. Your suggestion about max-heap would only make it more like what you're complaining about.

Comment: I think the amount of explanation you've provided on top of naming the algorithm is sufficient. However, I think the bit about "maintained in inverse order" is superfluous at best and confusing at worst. You seem to imply that heaps are _min_ heaps are the default, but in fact it is completely arbitrary to have a min heap or a max heap. It is entirely application dependent which way you want to organize, and you can always negate your values before throwing them into the heap if it's the "wrong" kind of heap.

Comment: @SchighSchagh As the poster has now put his own question into the inverse, I can now remove it completely ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just use std::set to do that, since in std::set all values are sorted from min to max.

```
void insert_value(std::set<ResultType>& myset, const ResultType& value){
    myset.insert(value);
    int limit = 10; 
    if(myset.size() > limit){
       myset.erase(myset.begin());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is easier to understand and implement than the heap solutions, and has the same run-time complexity. +1

Comment: Firstly, I think you need to use `std::multiset`, as it's probably valid to have repeated values. Secondly, `myset.erase(myset.rbegin())` doesn't work -- `rbegin()` returns the wrong iterator type. You'd need to use a `multiset` with a `std::greater` comparitor and call `myset.erase(myset.begin())` instead. Lastly, while the algorithmic complexity is the same, a typical RB-tree implementation of `std::[multi]set` will most likely be much slower than a (partially) sorted `vector` of 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think MaxHeap will work for this problem.

```
1- Create a max heap of size 10.
2- Fill the heap with 10 elements for the first time.
3- For 11th element check it with the largest element i.e root/element at 0th index.
4- If 11th element is smaller; replace the root node with 11th element and heapify again.
```

Repeat the same steps until the whole file is parsed.

Comment: I think you have it all backwards. I think OP is trying to keep the lowest values, and you are popping the lowest. Use max heap to pop highest instead.

Comment: I think he wants to keep the highest values, so remove all the lowest values and you will be left with highest values only. Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: Quoting OP, `I will simply ... remove the largest floating point that was in the vector, ...`

Comment: Title says keeping 10 highest number while content says otherwise.. Please add the comment in the question for correct the same...

Comment: Looks like OP just changed the title to say "lowest".

Comment: sorry my bad. It's late at night and I didn't change the title on time.